# How to configure the main sidebar menu in a React-Admin app

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

My app uses React-Admin version [2.9](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/2.9/Tutorial.html) and I'm trying to determine how to customize the app's main sidebar menu.

When I add [Resource](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/2.9/Resource.html) items to the app's [Admin](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/2.9/Admin.html) component, they appear in the sidebar, but in a seemingly partially random order. Some are in the same order as they are in my Admin component, while others are not. Is there some way to specify the ordering of these items?

It's also a bit mysterious to me how to specify which Resource items even appear on that main sidebar menu. I eventually figured out that resources only appear on the sidebar if I give them an `options.label` attribute. Is that the intended mechanism for specifying that a Resource should appear in the sidebar? Or is there some other, perhaps more intuitive, way to mark a Resource as one to appear in the sidebar? The [documentation](https://view-source:https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/2.9/Resource.html) simply states "*options.label allows to customize the display name of a given resource in the menu.*"

Answer (score 1):

Resources appear in the sidebar if you provide them a `list` component, e.g.

```
<Resource name="posts" list={PostList} />
```

Has a menu entry, but

```
<Resource name="posts"  />
```

does not. This is because there would be nothing to lead to.

The order in the menu is the order of the children in the `<Admin>` component. If it is not in your case, it may be because you have dynamic resources (i.e. you add some Resources after the first render). In that case, you should build a Menu by hand, as explained in the documentation:

```
// in src/MyMenu.js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { MenuItemLink, getResources, Responsive } from 'react-admin';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const MyMenu = ({ resources, onMenuClick, logout }) => (
    <div>
        {resources.map(resource => (
            <MenuItemLink
                key={resource.name}
                to={`/${resource.name}`}
                primaryText={resource.options && resource.options.label || resource.name}
                leftIcon={createElement(resource.icon)}
                onClick={onMenuClick}
            />
        ))}
        <MenuItemLink to="/custom-route" primaryText="Miscellaneous" onClick={onMenuClick} />
        <Responsive
            small={logout}
            medium={null} // Pass null to render nothing on larger devices
        />
    </div>
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    resources: getResources(state),
});

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(MyMenu));
```

More details at https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/2.9/Theming.html#using-a-custom-menu

Note: react-admin 2.9 is not maintained since 3 years, I strongly advise you to upgrade to version 4.

Comment: Interestingly, I have Resource items in my Admin component which do have a list component, but do not appear in the sidebar. However, after I add an options.label, then they do appear in the sidebar. So this is still a bit of a mystery to me. Perhaps this is different in later versions, but this is what I'm seeing in the 2.9 React-Admin version.

Comment: I do really hope to upgrade to a recent React-Admin version. I have been seeking an example with just a login button (no username/password form fields), similar to the OpenID example on the [Advanced Tutorials page](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/AdvancedTutorials.html) of the React-Admin online docs. Unfortunately, that example uses v2.9.